# No resonance in Anti Aromatic compounds

Tags: organic-chemistry, resonance

My teacher commented on Anti aromatic compounds as being less stable compounds as *it doesn't undergo resonance* inspite of *having π-bonds/electron pairs* in **conjugation**. I didn't understand why so. Can you help?

Answer (score 2):

As according to Molecular Orbital theory , when anti- aromatic compound is formed, the electron goes to anti bonding, and is unpaired even, which reduces it's stability.,
Or we can say that in anti- aromatic,the plane of electron cloud twists there bonds between carbons, making it unstable, thus resonance is not possible.
Antiaromaticity is a characteristic of a cyclic molecule with a π electron system that has higher energy due to the presence of 4n electrons in it. Unlike aromatic compounds, which follow Hückel's rule ([4n+2] π electrons) and are highly stable, antiaromatic compounds are highly unstable and highly reactive. To avoid the instability of antiaromaticity, molecules may change shape, becoming non-planar and therefore breaking some of the π interactions.
Greater the delocalisation energy(resonance energy) of a compound, more stable it is. The resonance energy can be calculated using Huckel Molecular Orbital Theory(HMOT). Antiaromatic compounds have zero resonance energy hence are unstable.
According to HMOT,
Delocalisation energy=( Pi electron binding energy) - (total energy of isolated double bonds in a classical structure)